# PHP - If domain

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following piece of coding on a multi-domain 1 template setup:

```
<?php  $host = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
if($host == 'www.justdoors.co') {
echo "action goes here";
} ?>
```

For some reason it's not carrying out the action when I'm on the www.justdoors.co domain, what am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `$domain`?

Comment: What is the value of `$host` when you are on that domain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable

```
 $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
 if($host == "www.justdoors.co" or $host == "justdoors.co") {
     //do anything you want to do 
 }
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is not always true. HTTP_HOST will have a '.' at the end if you make the host absolute: `http://example.org./` (`http://example.org/` [without the dot] is relative).

Comment: You should never ever trust user input.

Comment: Sure, in case it's security issue, it should be SERVER_NAME. In case it's template selection, ONLY USER losts something

Answer (score 7):

I have used this successfully on my server before.

```
<?php if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.domain.com' ) { echo ''; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it's working perfectly ..

```
<?php
function conn()
{
    $ora_con=0;
    //development connection building
    if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'xyz.com' ) 
    {$username='scott';
     $password = 'tiger';
     $ora_conn_string = 'conn_name:port_no/db_name';
     //echo "<br>development connection building";
      $ora_con = oci_connect($username,$password,$ora_conn_string);
     //echo '<br>dev connection build<br>';
    }
    //Production connection building
    elseif ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'abc.net' ) 
        {$username='prod_scott';
         $password = 'prod_tiger';
         $ora_conn_string = 'conn_name:port_no/db_name';
         //echo "<br>Production connection building";
         $ora_con = oci_connect($username,$password,$ora_conn_string);
         //echo '<br>Prod connection build<br>';
        }

    return $ora_con;
}
?>
```